# Injectivity of Physical Functions

Tags: laws-of-physics

Consider all functions in nature (except path functions like work) like internal energy, modulus of elasticity, electrical resistance of a material, etc.

1) Is there any function (as described above) in nature that is **not** an [injective function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Injective_function)?

If the answer to question 1 is **no**, then

2) Can we prove that all functions in nature, except path functions, are injective functions?

Comment: I've deleted some comments which should have been answers. Please keep in mind that comments are not to be used for answering the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since David Z wants us to write a trivial comment's worth of a remark as an answer:

1) Plenty of such functions exist. The radial distance of a planet as a function of angle is one. In general all periodic functions are non-injective.

2) No, since it's not true. I am not even sure how one would define "path function" rationally.

Comment: Thank you because of your attention dear CuriousOne ank thanks a lot to dear DavidZ. My English isn't good, but I guess you flouted me in your first sentence. No problem. I think everyone has something to say. If we cannot understand him/her, we mustn't flout him/her. Anyway, I couldn't understand first part of your answer. But the second part: If you say that in a periodic motion, position is function of time, then I should say that position **is determined** by time and it isn't a function of time. For example, is R a function of V and I ($R=\frac{V}{I}$) or R related to material features?

Comment: We should understand difference between mathematics and physics.